# Prevent textarea and mirrored content in a flex element from expanding dynamically with content

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am attempting to prevent a flex element that mirrors text from a nested textarea from growing, but I want it to originally take up space. Is there a way to do this with flexbox, or should I switch to using grid?

The card holding the text area is *not* supposed to be growing with its content. This only grows because the element below mirrors its content. I have tried `overflow: scroll`, but to no avail.

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let copy = document.getElementById("copy");
text.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  copy.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
.card-holder {
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  margin: 10px;
  
  gap: 10px;
}
.card {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;

  padding: 10px;

  flex-grow: 2;
}
.widget {
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;

  gap: 10px;
}
.widget.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  
  padding: 10px;
}

#copy {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  
  background: #EEE;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="card-holder">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="widget vertical">
        <textarea id="text" rows="10" columns="5" placeholder="Insert a large amount of text here"></textarea>
        <div id="copy">
          I'll grow too
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="glass card">
      More stuff here too
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59839938/preventing-a-flex-item-from-growing-with-content), but the only answer is not suitable.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182743/how-to-prevent-a-flex-box-from-growing-with-content) answer also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flex-grow` property on card is causing it.
In this case, it appears that you are only using flex as a convenience method to make it so that the left and right side always fill the space equally and remain centered.

You can replace `flex-grow: 2;` with `width: 100%;` for the same effect.

```
.card {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```js
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let copy = document.getElementById("copy");
text.addEventListener("input", function(event){
  copy.textContent = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
.card-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  margin: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  background-color: #EEE;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.widget {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 10px;
}

.widget.vertical {
  flex-direction: column;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#copy {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: solid 1px #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="card-holder">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="widget vertical">
                <textarea id="text" rows="10" columns="5" placeholder="Insert a large amount of text here"></textarea>
                <div id="copy">
                    I'll grow too
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="glass card">
            More stuff here too
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: You are still using the rest of the css right? I've testing in Chrome, IE 11, Edge, and Firefox.

Comment: Unless you mean for the bottom box to not expand vertically as well? I assumed you wanted to stop the horizontal growth.

Comment: My bad, I just tested with a string that had no spaces. Thanks!